# Create copy of variable sized Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table in one spreadsheet (Resource.xlsx), called "People". As new people join the organisation, this table grows in size.

I have another spreadsheet (Planning.xlsx) in which I'd like to have a dynamic replica of the data in Resource.xlsx. I.e. when I add a row to the table in Resource.xlsx, a new row is created in Planning.xlsx. I'd also like to be able to add additional columns to the duplicated table in Resource.xlsx.

In my head this seems like it ought to be fairly straightforward, but I'm struggling. Either that, or I'm using the wrong search terms! Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried making one sheet a data connection of the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't, as you have discovered, that straight-forward. Mainly because it isn't a job that Excel is particularly suited for! What you really want is a database!

Having got that out of the way, a couple of options present themselves but we need to understand a bit more scope. Do you want the changes to be instant or are you happy to have the 2nd workbook update at some later point?

If the former, you will need to write some VBA scripting in the 1st workbook that opens the 2nd workbook and watches for change events in the People table. When a change event happens, you check for a new line being added and then add it to the second table. The VBA will be reasonably involved (too long to write here I'm afraid) but not too difficult.

The second case is actually a LOT easier. Now you can base your second table on a query of the first. Since you want to add extra data to the second table, the easiest and most robust answer is to install Microsoft's free PowerQuery addin. Using this, create a query against the 1st table, add the extra columns you need and that is it. Whenever you update the 1st table, save, close and open the second then refresh the query (which can be set to happen when you open).

Comment: Thanks - it's what I thought. I'll probably move over to Access/SQL Server in that case.

Comment: Well, the 2nd method is certainly workable and I use it for a number of bits of complicated data analysis. However, if the data is important to you and has worth from a business perspective, it is probably worth having something a bit more robust. Do yourself a favour though - don't bother with Access if you can help it. Instead go for a database engine (SQL Server, MySQL or whatever) with a web front end. Far more flexible and robust in the long term.